# ERROR Updating the lib.so.6 file in Centos6.4

Tags: compiler-errors, centos, glibc

I have updated the glibc on centOS(6.4 64bit) from version 2.12 to 2.14 (Built it from source using the make and make install commands) but still the version of libc.so.6 remains 2.12 . Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Most likely because you didn't configure glibc-2.14 with correct prefix.

Do `make install` again, and see where the libc-2.14.so gets copied. Chances are, it goes into `/usr/local/lib`, which is not the right place for it on a Linux system.

More info [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html).